# Unlock login screen using command line

Tags: command-line, gnome, lock-screen

Is it possible to unlock the 13.04 Gnome shell login screen
from a command line? A user is logged in to Gnome shell, I can log in to a console as this user. I also have root access.

This is for accessing an active X11 display through VNC, without having to enter the password.

Executing

```
gnome-screensaver-command -d
```

as suggested in a [blog post](http://z-computer-z.blogspot.ch/2010/01/remote-lock-screen-and-remote-unlock.html) didn't help.

[image: login screen]

Comment: Is ssh throwing you any output or error?

Comment: @Braiam: I can `ssh` in, that's not the problem. It's for accessing an active X11 display through VNC, but without having to enter the password.

Answer (score 72):

I'm assuming you have a recent linux system with `systemd` (e.g. Ubuntu 16.04 or newer).

If you need to **unlock your own session**, just run `loginctl unlock-session` (no root required because it's your own session). If you have multiple sessions and want to select just one, run `loginctl list-sessions` to identify session and then run e.g. `loginctl unlock-session c187`.

If you need to **unlock all sessions**, just run `sudo loginctl unlock-sessions` (note plural form). Note that this will immediately unlock ALL sessions no matter which user is running the screen saver.

---

If you need more information to identify the correct session, you can try something like this:

```
loginctl list-sessions --no-legend | while read id rest; do echo; loginctl show-session $id; done
```

Comment: This is the only answer that works on 16.04

Comment: No need for sudo apparently

Comment: You need `sudo` if you want to unlock screen savers of ALL sessions (including sessions not running with your user id).

Comment: Also note the last `s` in `unlock-sessions`. If you want to unlock only your own session, just do `loginctl unlock-session`.

Comment: Try hitting `Tab` after `unlock-sessions` and type anything listed from it if `loginctl unlock-sessions` doesn't work for any reasons.

Comment: It should be the accepted answer!

Comment: It still works on 22.04

Comment: Yes, 22.04 is newer release than 16.04. This answer uses official `systemd` features so it should be okay until `systemd` is replaced with something else. I'm not aware of any project to do that so I'd expect this answer to be valid around year 2030, too.

Answer (score 23):

The problem with executing commands like `gnome-screensaver-command` from an SSH session is usually that they don't automatically connect to the appropriate session bus for the active desktop session - usually, setting the DISPLAY variable will fix that, for example these work for me (logged in via SSH as the same user who owns the locked X session, which is on DISPLAY :0):

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 gnome-screensaver-command -d
```

to unlock, and

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

to lock.

Alternatively, you can toggle the active state using `dbus-send` - for example

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0
$ dbus-send --session \
          --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver \
          --type=method_call \
          --print-reply \
          --reply-timeout=20000 \
          /org/gnome/ScreenSaver \
          org.gnome.ScreenSaver.SetActive \
          boolean:false
```

Source: https://people.gnome.org/~mccann/gnome-screensaver/docs/gnome-screensaver.html#gs-examples

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these methods unlocked the particular screen lock installed on my system (see screenshot). How can I find which process is responsible for locking the screen anyway?

Comment: Do the commands return an error? If so please post it. To see if a different screensaver is running you could try `ps -fu <username> | grep saver` - it is possible that `xscreensaver` is being used instead of `gnome-screensaver`, in which case you could try `DISPLAY=:0 xscreensaver-command -deactivate`.

Comment: I tested this answer on Ubuntu 14.04. It doesn't work. It unblanks the screen, but the screen remains locked.

Comment: `gnome-screensaver` is not present on Ubuntu 22.04 it seems. `gsd-screensaver` might be the replacement.

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me:

```
sudo killall gnome-screensaver
```

Especially helpful when you're logged in via SSH with another user.

Comment: Confirmed, I had this problem when keyboard wasn't typing on the unlock screen, but was able to switch to terminal using CTRL+ALT+F3 and this screensaver killer helped. Then I just went CTRL+ALT+F2 back to the session that was locked :)

Comment: This works when X2Go is showing the lock screen and not responding :)

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem with gnome 3's screen lock (screensaver) being stuck at a blank screen. I managed to work around it by *replacing* the gnome-shell window manager.

Ctrl+Alt+F1 and log in on a virtual console, then:

```
pkill -QUIT gnome-shell
DISPLAY=:0.0 gnome-shell -r &
```

(`&` Backgrounds the new gnome-shell so you can log out of the virtual console and keep it running. Alternatively use Ctrl+Z to suspend the gnome-shell process, and `bg` to background it.)

It might not be elegant, but it finally allowed me to get back to my desktop apps without having gnome force me to logout.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and see if restarting `gnome-shell` works for me.

Comment: sending `HUP` instead of `QUIT` makes the second command unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where the unlock screen wouldn't accept keyboard input sometimes.  The way I finally solved it was to kill the *several* `gnome-screensaver` processes that were running, as well as one `gnome-screensaver-dialog` process.  I'm guessing that whatever process was spawning 2 gnome-screensaver sessions was messing up my unlock screen.  I'm actually supposed to be using xscreensaver instead, so maybe that messed with it.

Anyways, `Ctrl+Alt+F1`, look for screensaver processes running `ps -aux | grep screen` and kill them all.  The gnome and xscreensaver commands listed in the other answers didn't work for me.