# How can I lock the screen using the new lockscreen from the command line?

Tags: unity, command-line, 14.04, lock-screen

Ubuntu 14.04 introduces [a new lockscreen](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/03/unity-lockscreen-ubuntu-14-04) that looks similar to the login screen.

[image: New lockscreen]

I am still able to lock the screen using the command `gnome-screensaver-command --lock` (as I always did before), which under 14.04 does lock the screen, but:

- If you are running it from the desktop, it locks the screen using the new lockscreen.
- If you are running it from a virtual console or via SSH, it locks the screen using the **old lockscreen**.

I've also tried using `xdg-screensaver lock`, but it works in the same way as `gnome-screensaver-command --lock` does (only uses the new lockscreen when it's ran from the desktop).

Running `light-locker-command --lock` didn't work, as `light-locker` is not installed.

I guess there must be some differences between running the same command from the desktop and running it via SSH/virtual console, but I was not able to find any difference in the environment variables.

So, my question is: **How can I lock the screen using the new Unity lockscreen and not the old lockscreen from the command line?**

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455926/unlock-screen-in-14-04-without-gnome-screensaver-command) is probably related as it asks for the new command that needs to be used, so here's another question: **Why does running the same lock command give different results?**

Note that `gnome-screensaver` is not being used anymore in 14.04, according to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1307163):

> That's not really a gnome-screensaver bug, that component stopped being used in trusty.

Comment: I would like to know as well. Using `dm-tool lock` comes close: it locks the screen, but (unlike the default Unity lock screen) also allows you switch users.

Comment: `dm-tool lock` and `dm-tool switch-to-greeter` seem to be doing the same thing: take you back to the log in screen (greeter), which does look very similiar to the lockscreen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't have `gnome-screensaver` installed, and the only command I can find that works is this:

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock
```

Comment: `qdbus org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock`

Comment: This used to work, but it seems not to work anymore in 15.10 :/

Comment: @LéoLam  Are you using a livecd image? I'm still using 14.04, but I did test both my command and Aquarius Power's in 15.10 and got them to work. However, I had to enable the lock screen to get it to work via this command `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false`

Comment: Nope, it's on a real Ubuntu install. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen` returns `false`. Now there's no output at all when running dbus-send. Maybe gnome-screensaver is needed for this to work?

Comment: I tested 15.10 without gnome-screensaver (though xscreensaver was installed instead) and it still worked fine. Not sure what the problem is...

Comment: See my answers please, perhaps 15.10 has abandoned using the `org.gnome.ScreenSaver` dbus interface , so it's probably better idea to communicate with Unity's dbus interface

Answer (score 3):

I recently found out that
`xdg-screensaver lock`
works aswell and is quite a simple solution too!

Comment: It is mentioned in the OP that it does not work in all cases. Only when you're running it locally in a terminal from the GUI.

Comment: Worked for me remotely in an SSH session into an 18.04 LTS machine.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer has the right idea, except that the lockscreen is related to unity panel, while  `org.gnome.ScreenSaver` is obviously a Gnome-related type of schema,so it may or may not work.

There exists however a dbus interface for Unity, and all we need is to call this method `com.canonical.Unity.Session.Lock` like so

```
qdbus com.canonical.Unity  /com/canonical/Unity/Session com.canonical.Unity.Session.Lock
```

**Side note**:

The proof of the fact that it's related to unity panel is simple, when you have the screen locked, the process `/usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service` will change to `/usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service --lock-mode` as observed from tty1.

Comment: this does work in a graphical session, but fails in a SSH session even when setting $DISPLAY manually. "Service 'com.canonical.Unity' does not exist.".

Comment: This has nothing to do with `DISPLAY` variable , but with dbus. I'm not aware of whether over ssh Unity doesn't have a dbus session or not , so I can't help you in that part. I will ask around but so far that's as much as i can say.

Comment: Try running `dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-terminal` before that.  http://serverfault.com/a/411326

Comment: Can also connect to a screen/tmux session running inside X and run the command from there. Was my final workaround to connect to the right dbus session from a vterm.

Answer (score 2):

You can always send the keystrokes: `xdotool key super+l`.