# How do I lock the desktop screen via command line on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, gnome-screensaver

gnome-screensaver is not being used anymore in 14.04 ((((

How do I lock the desktop screen via command line on Ubuntu 14.04?

Please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I lock the screen using the new lockscreen from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457204/how-can-i-lock-the-screen-using-the-new-lockscreen-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

The command `gnome-screensaver-command -l` will lock Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.