# Lock screen with gnome-screensaver-command as root (from /etc/pm/sleep.d script)

Tags: suspend, 15.10, lock-screen, screensaver, dbus

My system (Ubuntu 15.10) has a bug: I have enabled "Require my password when waking from suspend" on the "Brightness & Lock" settings panel, but it does NOT ask for my password, which is incredibly insecure.

As a workaround, I'm trying to write a script which will live under `/etc/pm/sleep.d`. It should be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "${1}" in
  hibernate)
    # Do nothing
    ;;
  resume|thaw)
    su -c "gnome-screensaver-command --lock" MYUSERNAME
    ;;
esac
```

Problem is, this doesn't work; the `gnome-screensaver-command`  fails with the following message:

```
** Message: Failed to get session bus: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

Then, I tried to change the command to:

```
su MYUSERNAME -c "export $(dbus-launch) && gnome-screensaver-command -l"
```

Which then fails with:

```
** Message: Failed to get session bus: The connection is closed
```

So, the question is: what would be the right way to do this?

Comment: Not sure, but this might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/457204/how-can-i-lock-the-screen-using-the-new-lockscreen-from-the-command-line/492963

Answer (score 2):

You need to export `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` of the remote machine in your ssh before using `dbus` commands

You have to find it locally on the machine to which you want send commands remotely by typing the command:

```
set | grep DBUS
```

This will give you the shells current `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` value which you should export in your ssh shell after connecting to the remote machine and then enjoy.

Comment: Hi! A couple of points: 1) there is **no** remote machine. This is all one machine (my own, local). I never mentioned a remote machine in my question. 2) "You need to export `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`" --> this is exactly what the second attempt does: `export $(dbus-launch)`. This does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by reading the right `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` from the current gnome session.  Full example:

```
dbus_address=$(xargs -n 1 -0 < /proc/`pgrep gnome-session`/environ | grep DBUS)
su USERNAME -c "export $dbus_address && gnome-screensaver-command -l"
```