# Remove necessity to press "enter" to login

Tags: login

I'm used to windows 8, where if you put your password correctly it already login automatically. Sometimes when I use ubuntu I keep looking for it to login for 10 seconds before recognizing I need to press enter.

Is there somehow to remove that? Maybe writing a single script and put it somewhere to load together with system resources? Like if (pass = 12345){press return"} or anything like that. But I don't know if that would affect the system's behavior on other applications or anything in general.

Comment: You could use Blue Proximity.

Comment: oh look, thats interesting software, even that i hardly set bluetooth on on mobile because it drains battery. but it will surely help me. thanks =)

Comment: You will need to use this answer in 14.04: http://askubuntu.com/questions/455926/