# upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04, lock screen is stuck

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, lock-screen, 18.04

Right now I'm upgrading a fairly clean install of 16.04 to 18.04 and it seems to be stuck.

I mean, after some time into the upgrade it went on screen lock and I typed my username and password and it seems to be stuck saying: 'unlocking...'

No idea if this is due to the update still running hogging system resourcing or something else is going on.

I can switch with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>keys but that just gives me black screens and impossible to tell if the upgrade is still running/finished of something terrible happened...

Any idea's? (cant log in with `ssh` because I haven't installed ssh server on this laptop)

Comment: now also using alt ctrl + F keys is unresponsive.

Comment: Have you tried switching to a terminal (ctrl+alt+f4 or your favorite fn key) and logging in there, looking at what's happening (`top`, `iotop` etc)

Comment: @guiverc  as mentioned before, they give me a black screen instead of a login.

Comment: sorry I didn't know what CTRL+ALT+F did or meant (actually tried the combination on my 18.04 and it did nothing) never realizing you meant Fn keys.

Comment: @guiverc i mean the F-keys (F1 - F12)

Comment: if the HDD light is dead (no disk activity), or appears to be a very predictable pattern and it was mine, I'd wait as long as I could (eg. overnight), use another machine & then force-shutdown using power key and fsck, i may look for update logs (but not be surprised if I didn't find any due poweroff), and then try to continue dist-upgrade.  In the meantime (ie. overnight) you may get a better suggestion than this!

Comment: unfortunately this laptop does not have a HDD light. its been stuck for a couple of hours so i guess my only option left is to do a powercycle :(

Comment: Not much help now but the instructions say to turn off inactivity locking during install. I'll remember to put checks in my future wrapper script for upgrading.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix i completely missed that when i started the upgrade but good to remember for next time.  strikes me as a bit odd that something simple (and important apparently) like that is not handled by the upgrade script itself... or at least advertised in red capitals.

Comment: I'm also having this issue on a freshly installed system. After the reboot following the install, I can log in fine but once I lock the screen the system is unresponsive.

Comment: @geegee The instructions aren't given in the installation program. They are buried deep on some corner of the Internet. I just read them myself by accident on Sunday. My screens are never set to timeout so it wasn't a problem for me but I imagine it effects a great number of users. As mentioned I'm planning a wrapper script for `do-release-upgrade -d` to feed it all the Y's and N's necessary for unattended upgrade so I'll see about turning off inactivity lock screen at same time.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix
great!

Answer (score 37):

I stumbled into the same issue:
Upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 (on Kubuntu). Screen automatically locked because I didn't use the PC. Entered password, screen is stuck. Switching to the text console - all screens dark. Switching back, mouse courser appears and is responsive, but everything else black.

I then realized:

1. switching to text console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, the text console was *not empty* but just *very dark*. So I increased screen brightness on the laptop with the function keys.
2. using `top` I saw that the upgrade probably still running (heavy load on dpkg).
3. With `sudo loginctl unlock-sessions` I could unlock the screen savers. I learned this from this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/921726/859949%5D) (full quote for convenience, I used the ):

> `sudo loginctl unlock-sessions` if your system is using `systemd`. Note that the above will unlock ALL sessions no matter which user is running the screen saver.
>
> If you only want to unlock your own session, just run `loginctl unlock-session` (no root required because it's your own session).

After that, I changed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> back to KDE and found myself back to the still running session and upgrade process.

Comment: I'd give you a thousand upvotes if I could.  I absentmindedly locked my screen during my upgrade as I needed to walk away from the computer (at work).  Was able to ssh to the machine from another and issue the unlock-sessions command.  Thanks!!!

Comment: If there is no effect, make sure to add session id to the command `sudo loginctl unlock-sessions $SESSION_ID`. You can get the list of session ids by running `loginctl`.

Comment: Thanks for writing this up!

This still works for upgrading Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 as well.

The virtual console mappings have changed a bit in the last few years: it's CTRL+ALT+F5 to get to the text console, then CTRL+ALT+F2 to get back to UI session.

Comment: Thanks a lot OP and @ZhengQu ! I would have given you many more upvotes if it were possible :)

Answer (score 5):

I am also still having this issue, but I found a workaround - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> brings me to the normal login screen where I can enter my password and unlock the desktop.  This method keeps the original session, so your browser, terminal and other apps are where you left them.

Comment: I installed 18.04 on my laptop on the 4th (2 days ago) and this started happening to me yesterday. I'd already discovered that I can do the same thing (i.e.: pop over to the "switch user" screen) however, that is a bad solution since it doesn't really fix the problem. It does work though! So, yeah, thanks for contributing a workaround. I'm going keep looking for a fix and publish it here as soon as I find it.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, this problem can happen if your lockscreen is on a timeout.
So before upgrading make sure you unset a timeout for lockscreen.

To fix a stuck upgrade:
Powerdown the pc/laptop and reboot.

Most likely you will find yourself in a partially upgraded system.

In case if you see black screen on booting up, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> keys combination and it will take you to login prompt from where you can run below commands.

You can fix it with:

```
sudo dpkg --configure --pending
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: I think the last two commands should be `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Regardless, this had no effect for me.