# Terminal is frozen after using sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Tags: package-management, upgrade, kernel, update-manager

I tried to update my Ubuntu 16.04 through `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, but now the terminal is frozen (**terminal 1**).

I let it run for an entire day (more than 24 hours) and I just suspended the OS once.

I've already tried to follow some tips on the internet (e.g [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1030601)), but to no avail unfortunately.

Some piece of codes, that I found on the internet, I'm not able to use them, because the Ubuntu says that it `is locked by another process` (**terminal 2**).

Would anyone know what could be happening? Or what could I do to solve it? Because I don't know if was failed or successed, or if it is still running, because I've already tried to type some "enter"s, however nothing happens, neither it is created a new line on the terminal, it is frozen.

Thank you in advance.

**terminal 1**

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-148 linux-headers-4.4.0-148-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-148-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-148-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-148-generic linux-tools-4.4.0-148
  linux-tools-4.4.0-148-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-tools-virtual
4 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 69,1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 314 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-4.4.0-148-generic amd64 4.4.0-148.174 [12,0 MB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-image-4.4.0-148-generic amd64 4.4.0-148.174 [6.925 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-148-generic amd64 4.4.0-148.174 [36,6 MB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-generic amd64 4.4.0.148.156 [1.784 B]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-image-generic amd64 4.4.0.148.156 [2.750 B]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-4.4.0-148 all 4.4.0-148.174 [9.982 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-4.4.0-148-generic amd64 4.4.0-148.174 [810 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-generic amd64 4.4.0.148.156 [2.582 B]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-tools-4.4.0-148 amd64 4.4.0-148.174 [2.850 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-tools-4.4.0-148-generic amd64 4.4.0-148.174 [2.598 B]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-tools-virtual amd64 4.4.0.148.156 [2.610 B]
Fetched 69,1 MB in 2min 11s (526 kB/s)                                         
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-4.4.0-148-generic.
(Reading database ... 302549 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-4.4.0-148-generic_4.4.0-148.174_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-4.4.0-148-generic (4.4.0-148.174) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-4.4.0-148-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-148-generic_4.4.0-148.174_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-148-generic (4.4.0-148.174) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-148-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-148-generic_4.4.0-148.174_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-148-generic (4.4.0-148.174) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-generic_4.4.0.148.156_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic (4.4.0.148.156) over (4.4.0.146.154) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-generic_4.4.0.148.156_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic (4.4.0.148.156) over (4.4.0.146.154) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.4.0-148.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.4.0-148_4.4.0-148.174_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-148 (4.4.0-148.174) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.4.0-148-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.4.0-148-generic_4.4.0-148.174_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-148-generic (4.4.0-148.174) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-generic_4.4.0.148.156_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (4.4.0.148.156) over (4.4.0.146.154) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-tools-4.4.0-148.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-4.4.0-148_4.4.0-148.174_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-4.4.0-148 (4.4.0-148.174) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-tools-4.4.0-148-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-4.4.0-148-generic_4.4.0-148.174_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-4.4.0-148-generic (4.4.0-148.174) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-virtual_4.4.0.148.156_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-virtual (4.4.0.148.156) over (4.4.0.146.154) ...
Setting up linux-modules-4.4.0-148-generic (4.4.0-148.174) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-148-generic (4.4.0-148.174) ...
I: /vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-146-generic
I: /initrd.img.old is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-146-generic
I: /vmlinuz is now a symlink to boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-148-generic
I: /initrd.img is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-148-generic
Setting up linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-148-generic (4.4.0-148.174) ...
Setting up linux-image-generic (4.4.0.148.156) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.4.0-148 (4.4.0-148.174) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.4.0-148-generic (4.4.0-148.174) ...
```

**terminal 2**

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure --pending
dpkg: error: dpkg frontend is locked by another process

$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error: dpkg frontend is locked by another process

$ sudo apt -f install
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to share the steps I did to fix the problem.

First, I needed to close the terminal manually. Then, I had to remove the lock:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

After that, I was able to execute the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --configure --pending

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt install -f
```

Thank you to the [Linux group](https://t.me/LinuxParaTodos) members that helped me to solve this question and the others that tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Almost identical to this situation: [Ubuntu 18.04 stuck at upgrading linux-header](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068828/ubuntu-18-04-stuck-at-upgrading-linux-header)

The accepted answer there with 5 upvotes (6 now) is below

---

**TLDR: Disable Secure Boot.**

I started having this same issue about a month ago. For me it turns out the solution was disabling Secure Boot. I've had Secure Boot disabled since I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and it's upgraded without any problems. However, about a month ago, I updated my BIOS which re-enabled Secure Boot (I didn't know this at the time). It was frustrating having the upgrades freeze and I finally figured it out because my VirtualBox installation was also not working. The fix for VirtualBox was disabling Secure Boot which also fixed my `linux-headers-<version>-generic` upgrades.

As noted in the question, it would freeze here:

```
...
Setting up linux-headers-4.15.0-38-generic (4.15.0-38.41) ...
```

After disabling Secure Boot, I get:

```
...
Setting up linux-headers-4.15.0-38-generic (4.15.0-38.41) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Another more easy way to upgrade your Ubuntu version it through this command:

```
do-release-upgrade
```